# I want to know How to Segregate Digits Chars and Special Chars In Sql server Using CTE?

Tags: sql-server

I have a string which contains characters,special characters and numbers in it.

what i have to do this i have to seperate all  characters into one column and special characters into to another column and numbers into another column using common table expression.it would be helpful for me if anyone provide the  code by using common table expression  for obtaining the required result.

The Code what I have Tried So far:

```
DECLARE @search VARCHAR(200)
    SET @search='123%#'
;with cte (Num,indexing) as (
SELECT
@search,0
UNION ALL
SELECT

indexing
num

from
cte
cross apply
(select indexing+1) C(NewLevel)
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT REPLACE(Num, NewLevel, '')) C2(NewInput)
WHERE 
indexing<=LEN(NUM)


)
select Num
from cte
```

My input Should be:abcd12345$@##

my Expected Output is:

```
Column 1         Column 2       Column 3
12345            $@###           abcd
```

[image: my expected output should be like this]

Comment: FYI, good use of white space is a must when writing readable SQL. Take the time to format your code, it'll make things for both yourself and others reading your code far easier. For example, it's very difficult (in the above) to see where that CTE starts and end.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Larnu  Ms Sql Server 2019

Comment: @Larnu   Why did you use these many nulls VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)) can we do this problem in much  simpler way

Comment: @Larnu If you dont mind can you solve this problem by using rcte because i have to do this problem by using rcte

Comment: Why are you commenting under the question in regards to my answer? Comment in the answer if the comment is about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would, personally, use a Tally to split the string into separate characters, and then use conditional string aggregation to create the new strings:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(200) = 'abcd12345$@##';
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@YourString))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4),
Chars AS(
    SELECT V.YourString,
           SS.C,
           T.I,
           CASE WHEN SS.C LIKE '[A-z]' THEN 'Letter'
                WHEN SS.C LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 'Number'
                ELSE 'Special'
           END AS CharType
    FROM (VALUES(@YourString)) V(YourString)
         CROSS JOIN Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.YourString,T.I,1)))SS(C))
SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE CharType WHEN 'Letter' THEN C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I) AS Letters,
       STRING_AGG(CASE CharType WHEN 'Number' THEN C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I) AS Numbers,
       STRING_AGG(CASE CharType WHEN 'Special' THEN C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I) AS Special
FROM Chars
GROUP BY YourString;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb6647514b8f37cfef0dfaf07cf9f363)

*Note, as well, the use of whitespace, so yo can clearly see where one CTE starts and another begins.*

---

#### Explanation

The first CTE (`N`), is just 10 `NULL` values. I use 10 as multiples of 10 are easy to work with.

Then next CTE (`Tally`) creates a Tally table. It Cross joins `N` to itself 4 times, creating 10^4 rows, or 10,000 rows, each with an incrementing number, due to `ROW_NUMBER`. We don't need all of those rows, however, so I limit it to the length of your variable.

Then we get onto `Chars`; this splits the string into its individual characters, 1 row per character, numbers them and defines the type they are, a Letter, Number or Special Character.

Then we finally, after the CTEs, aggregate the values using a conditional `STRING_AGG`, so that only the character type you want is aggregated in the column.

---

If you "must" use a rCTE, you can do it this way, but, like I have mentioned, a rCTE is a far slower solution and suffers from maximum recursion errors (If you have more than 100 characters, you'll need to change the `MAXRECURSION` value in the `OPTION` clause):

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(200) = 'abcd12345$@##';
WITH Chars AS(
    SELECT V.YourString,
           1 AS I,
           SS.C,
           CASE WHEN SS.C LIKE '[A-z]' THEN 'Letter'
                WHEN SS.C LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 'Number'
                ELSE 'Special'
           END AS CharType
    FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@YourString,1,1)))SS(C)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.YourString,
           C.I + 1 AS I,
           SS.C,
           CASE WHEN SS.C LIKE '[A-z]' THEN 'Letter'
                WHEN SS.C LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 'Number'
                ELSE 'Special'
           END AS CharType
    FROM Chars C
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@YourString,C.I + 1,1)))SS(C)
    WHERE C.I + 1 <= LEN(C.YourString))
SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE CharType WHEN 'Letter' THEN C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I) AS Letters,
       STRING_AGG(CASE CharType WHEN 'Number' THEN C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I) AS Numbers,
       STRING_AGG(CASE CharType WHEN 'Special' THEN C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I) AS Special
FROM Chars
GROUP BY YourString;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0843057d8dab21abae4b44914b0e3b30)

Comment: @larnuThanks bro,It means a lot to me and it is also very useful for me.

Comment: If it answers the question, please do mark it as the solution so that future readers know it was helpfu, thanks. *I'm not your "bro" though, we aren't related. (My Brother knows nothing about SQL, he  works in Shipping).*

Comment: @Kartheek multiples of 10 are easy to work with. An alternative approach would be an rCTE, but they are [far slower than a tally](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/) when working with larger data sets, so I only use them if I must; this isn't one of those times.

Comment: *"because i have to do this problem by using rcte"* You stated you needed to use a CTE, not an rCTE. I would stick to the Tally, as I mentioned, they are *far* faster.

Comment: Sorry man i didnt see when i was commenting,could you solve the problem by using rcte

Comment: I could, yes, but I've used a TAlly here, like I said, they're far faster.

Comment: i am not understanding this cte which you used tally in the cte,please could you rewrite the problem by using rcte

Comment: If you don't understand it, I'm happy to explain it, I'll add an edit.

Comment: If you Dont mind please edit the code man by using rcte .

Comment: Have added an explanation for you.

Comment: if you dont mind can you Please  do the same problem by using rcte because i want this problem to be done in rcte method

Comment: @Kartheek I've used a Tally for a reason here.

Comment: Added an rCTE, but, like I said, it'll be slower for more values, @Kartheek .